# How Do I Create A 2 Column Form WIth React Material-UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am creating a react form with material-ui.

I would like the form to be a fixed 2 column view and not flow based on the browser size so it is always like this:

```
|First Name      |Last Name|
|Street Address  |City     |
```

And not end up like

```
|First Name      |Last Name|  Street Address  |City     |
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0q7kw76nyl

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const styles = theme => ({
  textField: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    marginRight: theme.spacing.unit
  }
});

class TextFields extends React.Component {
  state = {
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
    street: "",
    city: ""
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;

    return (
      <form className={classes.container} noValidate autoComplete="off">
        <TextField
          id="first-name"
          label="First Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          value={this.state.firstName}
          onChange={this.handleChange("firstName")}
          margin="normal"
        />

        <TextField
          id="last-name"
          label="Last Name"
          className={classes.textField}
          value={this.state.lastName}
          onChange={this.handleChange("lastName")}
          margin="normal"
        />

        <TextField
          id="address-street"
          label="Street Address"
          className={classes.textField}
          value={this.state.street}
          onChange={this.handleChange("street")}
          margin="normal"
        />

        <TextField
          id="address-city"
          label="City"
          className={classes.textField}
          value={this.state.city}
          onChange={this.handleChange("city")}
          margin="normal"
        />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

TextFields.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default withStyles(styles)(TextFields);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As above, putting into divs work great.

You can also put them inside a Grid layout for additional customization.

The grid layout has some neat additional such as spacing and justification of items, customizable items width, here's [the documentation](https://material-ui.com/layout/grid/).

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid'
<Grid container>
     <Grid item xs={6}> 
         ... 
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={6}>
         ...
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use both Grid container and item at the same time.

```
<Grid container spacing={2} >
  <Grid container item xs={6} direction="column" >
    <TextField />
    <TextField />
    <TextField />
  </Grid>
  <Grid container item xs={6} direction="column" >
    <TextField />
    <TextField />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try separating the two groups into divs like so:

https://codesandbox.io/s/vy6k6w1jq3

```
<div>
 <TextField/>
 <TextField/>
</div>
<div>
 <TextField/>
 <TextField/>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks cleaner and simpler and works in the sandbox, but weirdly for some reason doesn't stay the same in the more complicated page (they become vertical groups instead of horizontal!). So I'll have to go with Grids.

Comment: @opticyclic yes i hoped the simpler solution would suffice. Grid/Flexbox would do the trick